# qml add many procedural generated elements

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I need to add many spheres in a 5x5x5 pattern (in a 3d scene, but my guess is that the process doesn't differ if I'm in a 3D scene or not). This pattern can be generated easily in code, but is there a way to first generate the objects and then add them automatically to the qml?
I could hard code all spheres, but I would prefer a generation-based solution.

My Current Data Classes:

```cpp
#ifndef LED_H
#define LED_H

struct LED
{
    int x, y, z;
    bool on;
};

#endif // LED_H
```

```cpp
#ifndef CUBE_H
#define CUBE_H

#include <array>
#include "LED.h"

using std::array;


class Cube
{
    array<array<array<LED, 5>,5>, 5> leds{};

public:
    Cube()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; ++k)
                {
                       leds[i][j][k] = LED{ i, j, k, false };
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

#endif // CUBE_H
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how to pass C++ objects to QML?

Comment: @JarMan I see your point. I added the C++ code as an example how easy the objects can be generated. But I don't know how to add these to the qml. If you can do this with c++, then okay.
I only want to know how to add (generated) Data (if c++ or js, i dont care) to qml

Comment: Here's the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) for how to integrate C++ objects into QML. Alternatively, here's the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) for how to dynamically create QML objects from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To create objects quickly with minimal code, I recommend using `Repeater`. Here's an example to draw `5 * 5 * 5 === 125` circles quickly:

```
Repeater {
  model: 5 * 5 * 5
  delegate: Rectangle {
    property int i: index % 5
    property int j: Math.floor(index / 5) % 5
    property int k: Math.floor(index / 25)
    x: i * 20 + k * 4
    y: j * 20 + k * 4
    width: 20
    height: 20
    radius: 10
    color: "orange"
    border.color: "black"
  }
}
```

[image: 125 circles]